# Is it bad practice to have many classes subscribe to AppDelegate notifications?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I've seen code where eight different classes subscribe to the `appDidBecomeActive` and the `appDidEnterBackground` notifications. It seems like it's hard to keep track of what's going on if observers are littered throughout the codebase. Is it more common/easier to have only AppDelegate respond to these events and have it call functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of responsibility. If a class knows that it must perform specific actions when the app goes between the foreground and background then that class should respond to those notifications and do what it needs to do. No other class should have that knowledge.

That's a much better and more flexible design than only handling the events in one class which then has to know about all of the other classes and their needs.

It may seem disorganized to have lots of classes all respond to a given notification but the knowledge of what each class needs to do is where it belongs - with each class.

Think about keyboard events. The keyboard notifications are defined at the window level but it's common to have many view controllers respond to keyboard events. No one would consider only have the app delegate or key window respond to the keyboard events. It's no different for the "AppDelegate" notifications.